# How to divide two columns and discriminate the result in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table as follows:

```
rating                    totalrate              nrrates
------------            --------------        -------------
1                            5                     1
2                           10                     2
3                            3                     1
```

I want to find all ratings that are => 4. A rating is totalrate divide by nrates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (totalrate/nrrates)>=4
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0038b/3)